# Have Only One Partition And Want to Change OS!

Tags: partitioning

I Have One partition  only in my zorin os
And now I have to move to Ubuntu.
And **i don't want   lose my data**

Tell me what shoud  I do

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132693/discussion-on-question-by-dixit-ram-have-only-one-partition-and-want-to-change-o).

Answer (score 4):

You never want to lose your personal data, and you are never going to lose it: you *should* have one, preferably two backups.

Even if you *could* install the new OS without installing, you should have a backup first. Something may go wrong while changing your system.

Yes, to change the operating system installed on a partition, it is preferred to reformat the partition. So you will erase your personal data as well, and after installation, place it back using one of your backup copies.

Comment: Judgmental much?  Yes, good advice, but the tone...

Comment: @ZeissIkon I hear too much of the same: users must be made clear that it all starts or stops with a good data backup. Nothing else matters. Someone who does not maintain any backups does not value the data, although that person may not realize.

Comment: It can be possible to shrink volume  like. Windows  and then put data in that shrinked  volume and install  os in first  partition

Comment: @vanadium Or, much more likely, a person without a good backup values the data, but doesn't know a good way to back it up.  Thumb drives aren't it; they aren't reliable.  Any other method adds up some cost somewhere, and not everyone has money to spend.  If you don't garage your car with a good security system (and maybe an armed guard or two), you don't value your car, right?  Default Ubuntu installation doesn't even segregate user data in a way that makes it easy to think about backup (say, putting it in a separated partition) by default...

Comment: @vanadium Don't forget, you catch more flies with honey than vinegar...

Comment: @DixitRam Changing partitions, however, can go wrong, and you still need a backup before you start.  External USB drive aren't very costly; if you're in USA, Amazon can have one on your front step in a couple days.  Another couple days to make the backup, if you have a lot of data (or a couple hours if you don't), and the same time again to verify the backup, and you're ready to proceed.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Documents, Pictures, Movies, Videos. That is how default Ubuntu installation seggregates user data. b.t.w., I edited the message to make it less harsh ;-) Message remains, though.

Comment: @vanadium Okay, they must have updated that -- the *second* time I installed Linux, I partitioned manually and put /home on a separate partition (to more easily *not* reformat it) and a lot of personal stuff stayed on my ex-Windows NTFS partitions.

Comment: I Found SOLUTION :-https://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted

Comment: @ZeissIkon Ackchyually, you catch more flies with vinegar because it smells like rotting fruit.

Comment: Nice you found a solution. Carefully read the red lines at the beginning of the article you are linking to, though.

Comment: To emphasize @vanadium 's advice: I've had partitions completely vanish when attempting to make very minor mods -- apparently, there was a bug in some versions of Ubuntu's partition manager (gparted was okay at the time, but wasn't part of the default install I had at the time).